# Grab DIV Hash From URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the suggested fiddle - http://jsbin.com/EzUTizuf/1/edit (because of the url navigation change the iframe from Codemirror JSBin goes to a blank page, which is why I didn't add a fiddle before)

I have an anchor navigating to #about.
When the window.location is equal to #about I want to execute a small function corresponding to that specific window location.

This is the last code I tried to do this.

```
if (window.location.href === "#about") {
    $('.about').show();
    document.title="About";
    alert("About DIV Shows Only From This URL!");
}
```

If anyone can help it'd be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here's the full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Grab DIV Hash</title>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1.0'>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; left: 0px;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    padding:0; margin:0;
    background: #7abcff;
}

nav { text-align: center; }
a { outline: none; color: #000; text-decoration: none;}
a:hover { color: #555; }
a:active { color: #333; }

h1 {
    margin-top: .25em;
    font: bold 2.75em Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) -1px 0, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 -1px, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0 1px, rgba(0,0,0,0.3) -1px -2px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.about').hide();

    function AboutPage() {
        if (window.location.href === "#about") {
            $('.about').show();
            document.title="About";
            alert("About DIV Shows Only From This URL!");
        }
    }

    AboutPage();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#about"><h1>About</h1></a>
    </nav>

    <div class="about">
        1) About link clicked!<br />
        2) This div should only be visible from whatever.com/#about
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Here's the suggested fiddle - http://jsbin.com/EzUTizuf/1/edit (because of the url navigation change the iframe from Codemirror JSBin goes to a blank page, which is why I didn't add a fiddle before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the conditional use `window.location.hash` instead of `window.location.href` to detect the value of the hash.

The code must also attach an event handler to `window.onhashchange` to detect when the hash has changed.  When the link is clicked jQuery's `ready` event is not fired since a new page is not being loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.about').hide();
    window.onhashchange = function(){
        if(window.location.hash === "#about"){
           $(".about").show();
           document.title="About";
        }
    };
});
```

**JS FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/H6DZH/

Comment: hash and href don't work. I think it has something to do with how the if statement is looking for window.location.hash === "about"

Comment: `$(document).ready()` won't be fired when you click the anchor.  Assign an event handler to the `window.onhashchange` event.

Comment: I didn't know there was a onhashchange event. This has been very helpful. Thanks!